# Investigate the convergence of $\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos x \ln x}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Investigate the convergence of $$\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos x \ln x}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}} \, dx$$

so first of all let's split the integral to:

$$I_1 = \int_1^2 \frac{\cos x \ln x}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}} \, dx, \hspace{10mm} I_2 = \int_2^\infty \frac{\cos x \ln x}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}} \, dx$$

I already showed that the limit of the integrand is $0$ when $x\to 1^+$. Therefore, $I_1$ converges since it's integrand is a continuous function.

Regarding to $I_2$. At first I tried to prove it converges absolutely (eliminating the $\cos x$) but it didn't workout. Anyway, I think it's diverges but I don't know how to demonstrate it.

Comment: This integral is related to [Bessel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and [Struve functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that

$$\ln(x)=_\infty o(\sqrt x)$$
so

$$\frac{|\cos (x)|\ln x}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}\le\frac{\ln x}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=_\infty o\left(\frac1{x^{3/2}}\right)$$
so we conclude the convergence of the given intgeral since the integral

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^{3/2}}$$
is convergent.

Comment: Why is it true that $1/{x^{3/2}}$ grows faster than $\ln x / x\sqrt{x^2-1}$?

Comment: As I explained we have $\ln(x)=_\infty o(\sqrt x)$ since by the L'Hôpital's rule
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt x}=0$$
and notice that $\sqrt{x^2-1}\sim_\infty x$.

Comment: I see. Basically you could **also** claim that $\ln(x) = o(x)$. So $\frac{x}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} =_\infty \frac{1}{x}$ and $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x} < \infty $.

Comment: The integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x}$ is divergent so for this reason I compared $\ln x$ with $\sqrt x$. Anyway, you're welcome:)

Answer (score 2):

For large enough $x$ you have $$\left| \frac{\cos x \ln x}{x^2} \right| \le \frac{\ln x}{2 x^2}.$$ You should have little difficulty showing that $$\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2} \, dx < \infty.$$

Comment: Where the $2$ came from?